# A maximum principle for elliptical operator in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, variational-analysis, elliptic-operators

It is well known that on bounded domain, weak and strong maximum principle works fine. However, I'm wondering if is there some version (with more hypothesis maybe) of this result for elliptical operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that, restricted to smooth bounded domains is uniformly elliptic.

Comment: In complex analysis, we know that any holomorphic function which is defined on $\mathbb{C}$ and has upper bound is a constant function. That is to say, in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, solution of $\Delta u=0$ have upper bound is constant. By freezing coefficients, solution of $a_{ij}u_{ij}=0$.......